# Java comparison library

Tags: comparison, guava, java

Is there a Java library which would allow me to do comparison operations such as

```
try {
  verify(a).isEqualTo(b);
  verify(a).isGreaterThan(b);
  verify(a).contains(b);
catch (AssetionError e) {
  ..
}
```

I was thinking of [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), but couldn't find anything, maybe I wasn't looking hard enough ;)

Comment: Are you looking for unit testing?

Comment: Maybe this is a bad idea.  Why would you want a library to do something like this?

Comment: there's JUnit, Mockito...

Comment: I believe the comparison depends entirely on the type. Assuming you have a parent class, which implements these functions, you can build an entire tree of custom objects, which can be 'compared'. But in the end it depends on the type of a and b, as rmlan already said.

Comment: @rmlan - a and b are arbitrary classes

Comment: Seems an odd thing to do. `verify(a).isEqualTo(b)` is just `a.equals(b)`; the second one is the same than `a.compareTo(b) > 0` and  the third one is meaningless for most of the classes, unless you add which method use for the test...

Comment: If they are arbitrary classes, you need to define what "equality" and comparison is with these objects. As mentioned above, you can implement the `equals(o)` method, or you can have the arbitrary classes implement the `Comparable` interface, and implement the `compareTo(o)` method. Otherwise, the JVM has no idea how to compare these arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) may be of interest. e.g.

```
 assertThat(actualPrice, greaterThan(minimumPrice));
```

It's normally used for unit testing, but it's simply providing a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and its use isn't restricted to the testing domain.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking to implement it in a testing framework based on jUnit, looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean Preconditions?  Guava has a series of Preconditions you can use in your methods.  For example, you could use:

```
     Preconditions.checkArgument(count > 0, "must be positive: %s", count);
```

Will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` with the associated message if the check fails.

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html